# Não se realiza update de uma collection PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Estou tentando atualizar um parâmetro em uma tabela, baseada em valores prévios de uma *collection*, ela vai atualizar o atributo idAcolhimento de um determinado id da tabela de documento. Criei também um insert em uma tabela de teste, que executa com perfeição, todos os atributos. Não entendi porque o update não está funcionando. Se alguém puder ajudar eu agradeço. Testei com um valor numérico no update, para ver se tinha algum problema na lógica, só que nesse caso fez o update sem problemas. Quando atribuo com uma variável NUMBER recebendo do atributo idDocumento ou um %type desse atributo, simplesmente não atualiza. Segue o script:

```
DECLARE

 doc NUMBER;
 CURSOR regCompara IS SELECT TO_NUMBER(SEQ_ID) AS seqColecao ,TO_NUMBER(c001) AS idPessoa, TO_NUMBER(c002) AS idDocumento, TO_NUMBER(c003) AS idAcolhimento  FROM APEX_collections
                                WHERE collection_name =  'COLECAO_DOCUMENTO_PESSOA';

 linhaRegCompara   regCompara%ROWTYPE;
 p_doc linhaRegCompara.idDocumento%TYPE;
BEGIN

--Faz um loop sem comparação atualizando o atributo do acolhimento
  IF :P60_ID_NOVO IS NOT NULL THEN
        OPEN regCompara;
                 LOOP
                  FETCH regCompara INTO linharegCompara;
                   EXIT WHEN regCompara%NOTFOUND ;
                   --doc := linhaRegCompara.idDocumento;               
                   update DOCUMENTO SET id_acolhimento = :P60_ID_NOVO WHERE id = p_doc;

                   insert into teste (id_acolhimento, id_doc,id_pessoa) values (:P60_ID_NOVO,linhaRegCompara.idDocumento,linhaRegCompara.idPessoa);

                 END LOOP ;
        CLOSE regCompara;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Prezados, Acabei por achar uma outra solução que resolveu o problema do update. Realizei um update, sem cursores, fazendo com selects aninhados. Porém não descobri o motivo porque não funcionou, do primeiro jeito. Se alguém souber o motivo por favor ajudem aí. Aí vai o comando que faz o update:  update documento set id_acolhimento = :P60_ID_NOVO 
    where id in (select id from documento where id in 
                 (select c001 FROM APEX_collections WHERE collection_name = 'COLECAO_DOCUMENTO_PESSOA'));

Answer (score 1):

Em alguns casos, dependendo da configuração do Oracle, vc precisa incluir o

```
commit;
```

Após a inserção, exclusão ou atualização de registros, senão ele não atualizará o banco.

Answer (score 0):

O `fetch` foi realizado na variável `linhaRegCompara`, enquanto que `p_doc` (utilizada na cláusula `where` do `update`) nunca foi inicializada, estando com o valor `null`.
Com isso, a condição nunca é satisfeita e nenhum registro é atualizado.

Comment: Na verdade ela não precisa ser inicializada, pois o p_doc é a variável que armazenará a coluna idDocumento, desde que a consulta traga algum resultado

Comment: p_doc é declarada no bloco declare, e é referenciada somente uma vez no programa, no where da clausula update. O fetch é realizado sobre linhaRegCompra, portanto seria necessário utilizar linharegcompra.iddocumento no update, no lugar de p_doc